In proving the Long Tubular Flow Theorem
Assume $F$ be a $C^1$ vector field from an open $\mathcal{U}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the autonomous ODE $x'=F(x)$. I want to prove the following statement:
(Long Tubular Flow Theorem) Let $x \in\mathcal{U}$ be a regular point, and let $\tau > 0$ be a point in the
domain $I_x$ of definition of the trajectory $\gamma_x$ of equation $x'=F(x)$ such that the
restriction of $\gamma_x$ to the interval $[0,\,\tau]$ is injective. Then, there are $\epsilon > 0$ and
a $C^k$ diffeomorphism $H : (-\epsilon,\,\tau+\epsilon) \times (-\epsilon,\, \epsilon)^{d−1}\rightarrow W$ onto a neighborhood
$W$ of $\gamma_x([0,\,\tau])$ such that $H(0) = x_0$ and the function
$$(-\epsilon,\,\tau+\epsilon) \rightarrow\mathcal{U},\,\,t \mapsto H(t,\,\xi_2,\cdots,\,\xi_d)$$
is a solution of $x'=F(x)$ for all $(\xi_2,\,\cdots,\,\xi_d) \in (-\epsilon,\,\epsilon)^{d−1}.$
I tried following the same proof for the former tubular flow theorem, in this case with the added hypothesis of injectivity only on a compact subset of the trajectory $\gamma_x([0,\,\tau])$, which allows us to conclude $\gamma_x$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism onto its image, by the Inverse Function Theorem. The problem is that we have to show there is an "equivalence" between all horizontal flows in the box $(\epsilon,\,\epsilon)^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and find one such $H$ for each partition of the compact set $\gamma_x([0,\,\tau])$ into transverse sections and to glue them, preserving it as a $C^k$ diffeomorphism and a solution to the equation $x'=F(x)$. It is sufficient to do it for two transverse sections and applying induction on the number of sections (which is finite by compactness.)
I'd appreciate any help or hint.

Let us assume that the flow $(\varphi_t)$ is complete (i.e. defined for all times $t\in \mathbb R$), which can be achieved by modifying $F$ outside of ball that contains the orbit segment of interest.
Let now $x_0$ be a point with $F(x_0)\neq 0$ and $N\subset \mathbb R^{d}$ a codimension $1$ manifold through $x_0$ that is transversal to $F(x_0)$. Consider the map $\psi\colon N\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^d$ defined by $\psi(x,t)=\varphi_t(x)$.
Claim 1. $D\psi(x_0,t)$ is injective for all $t\in \mathbb R$.
We consider the derivative as a linear map $T_xN \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^d$, sending $(\xi,a)$ to $D\varphi_t(x_0)\xi + aF(\varphi_t(x_0))$. Applying $D\varphi_t(x_0)^{-1}$ yields the equation $\xi + a F(x_0)=0$ and transversality implies $\xi=0$ and $a=0$.
Claim 2. There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that no two points in $N\cap B_\epsilon(x_0)$ are of the form $x,\varphi_t(x)$ with $|t|<\epsilon$.
You can prove this with the local flow box theorem.
Claim 3. If $T\in \mathbb R$ issuch that $[0,T]\ni t\mapsto \varphi_t(x_0)$ is injective, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that also $\psi\colon [0,T]\times (N\cap B_\epsilon(x_0))\to \mathbb R^d$ is injective.
Assume not. Then there are $x_n,x_n'\in N$ with limit $x_0$ and $t_n,t_n' \in [0,T]$ with $\psi(t_n,x_n)=\psi(t_n',x_n')$, but $(x_n,t_n)\neq (x_n',t_n')$. After choosing a subsequence and switching labels, we may assume that $s_n=t_n-t_n'\to s_0\ge 0$. But then $x_n'= \varphi_{t_n'}^{-1}\circ \varphi_{t_n}(x_n)=\varphi_{s_n}(x_n)$. If we had $s_0=0$, this would contradict Claim 2 for large $n$, hence $s_0> 0$. Taking limits we get $x_0=\varphi_{s_0}(x_0)$ and thus by the assumed injectivity, we must have $s_0\notin [0,T]$. So for large $n$, also $t_n-t_n'>T$ which is impossible.

In the setting of Claim 3, if we further reduce $\epsilon$, Claim 1 and the inverse function theorem guarantee that $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism. That's the one you're looking for (you can further use a local chart of $N$ to define it on $[0,T]\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)^{d-1}$).
